# HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream avoid ProtocolViolationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest

Is there any way to prevent `HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream` from throwing an exception when the method is `GET`?

I know that `HEAD` and `GET` should not contain a body in valid HTTP, but some servers accept bodies for these methods anyway (e.g., Elasticsearch's _search feature). I have to call some get API method that retrieves parameters from the request body.

```
var uri = new Uri(@"someurl");
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "*/*";
request.ContentType = "application/json";

var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject));
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (var writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: Remove the line `request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;` and check if it is working.

Comment: @ViVi it didn't help.

Comment: then change the method type to `POST` @Mykhalik

Comment: I cannot use `POST`, I have to call `GET` method that retrieves parameters from request body. So I need to have `GET` method with a request body.

Comment: Can you refer this [Code Project Article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/849034/Csharp-Web-API-HTTP-GET-with-a-Request-Body) and check if it helps?